# regex to match all whitespace except those between words and surrounding hyphens?

Tags: regex

I'd like to sanitize a string so all whitespace is removed, except those between words, and surrounding hyphens

`1234 - Text | OneWord , Multiple Words | Another Text , 456` -> `1234 - Text|OneWord,Multiple Words|Another Text,456`

```
std::regex regex(R"(\B\s+|\s+\B)"); //get rid of whitespaces except between words

auto newStr = std::regex_replace(str, regex, "*");
newStr = std::regex_replace(newStr, std::regex("*-*"), " - ");
newStr = std::regex_replace(newStr, std::regex("*"), "");
```

this is what I currently use, but it is rather ugly and I'm wondering if there is a regex I can use to do this in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(\s+-\s+|\b\s+\b)|\s+
```

Replace with `$1`, backreference to the captured substrings in Group 1. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aFgAOM/1). *Details*:

- `(\s+-\s+|\b\s+\b)` - Group 1: a `-` with one or more whitespaces on both sides, or one or more whitespaces in between word boundaries
- `|` - or
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces.

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/VA1wIh):

```cpp
std::string s("1234 - Text | OneWord , Multiple Words | Another Text , 456");
std::regex reg(R"((\s+-\s+|\b\s+\b)|\s+)");
std::cout << std::regex_replace(s, reg, "$1") << std::endl;
// => 1234 - Text|OneWord,Multiple Words|Another Text,456
```